# openstack installation: failed to set rdo repo on host

Tags: openstack

I have downloaded all the repos needed for openstack to local and set up the local repositories properly.

However, when i run the offline installer, i've got the following erros:

```
Preparing servers                                 [ ERROR ]

ERROR : Failed to set RDO repo on host IP.AD.DR.ESS:
RPM file seems to be installed, but appropriate repo file is probably missing in /etc/yum.repos.d/
Please check log file /var/tmp/packstack/20140710-130352-_rre6e/openstack-setup.log for more information
```

Comment: Did you find the solution to this, I am having the same problem :(

Answer (score 2):

The above did not work for me but here's what did:

I was trying to install Openstack using `packstack` on a Centos 7, but I accidentally installed the RHEL repository as well:

```
sudo yum install -y https://rdoproject.org/repos/rdo-release.rpm
```

So to resolve , do an `rpm -qa | grep rdo` (should feedback something like `rdo-release-**` ) and then `yum remove rdo-release-*` . Then try `packstack --allinone` again.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it this way,

On CentOS:

First check the installed repos

```
yum repolist
```

and remove all repos which are related to openstack (like previously used for other releases - kilo etc.)

then;

```
yum install -y centos-release-openstack-mitaka
```

and go to the link
https://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/openstack/

```
wget https://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/openstack/openstack-mitaka/rdo-release-mitaka-5.noarch.rpm

rpm -Uvh rdo-release-mitaka-5.noarch.rpm
```

thats all ;)

try, hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

You should run the packstack command with the '-d' option to enable debug information, and read through the generated log file.

It is possible that packstack ran into an issue when executing a command over ssh (like not being able to log in as root) and the error message you see is a misleading one.

Answer (score 0):

Also can vpdate for a different version:

```
$ yum install -y centos-release-openstack-wallaby
```

and

```
$ wget https://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/openstack/openstack-wallaby/rdo-release-wallaby-0.el8.noarch.rpm
$ wget https://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/openstack/openstack-wallaby/rdo-release-wallaby-1.el8.noarch.rpm

$ rpm -Uvh rdo-release-wallaby-0.el8.noarch.rpm
$ rpm -Uvh rdo-release-wallaby-1.el8.noarch.rpm
```